# Can this arrow function be shortened? Are these the same?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, member-functions

If I start with this:

```
const obj1 = {
    doSomething: () => {
        console.log('hello world 1');
    },
};
```

Can it safely be shortened? Are these the same?

```
const obj2 = {
    doSomething: () => console.log('hello world 2'),
};
```

Why is this one so strange?

```
const obj3 = {
    doSomething: console.log('hello world 3'),
};
```

I noticed `obj3` runs itself and can't do `obj3.doSomething()`.

https://repl.it/JEGD/1

Comment: 1 & 2 are identical, 3 evaluates `console.log` and stores the result (which is `undefined`)

Comment: Your `myFunction` variables are actually objects, not functions.

Comment: There's also the [member method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions): `const myFunction1 = {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('hello world 1');
    }
};` or [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind): `const myFunction3 = {
    doSomething: console.log.bind(console, 'hello world 3')
};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 and 2 are *almost* the same.

When you provide a statement (instead of a block) on the RHS of the arrow, the function returns the result of evaluating that statement.

In the first example, the function returns `undefined` because there is no `return` statement.

In the second example, the function returns `undefined` because `console.log` returns `undefined`.

There isn't a practical difference here, but there could be in similar cases.

---

As for the third example…

In case 1, you create a function with a function expression.

In case 2, you create a function with an arrow function.

In case 3, you don't create a function at all.

You call `console.log` **immediately** and assign its return value (which, as I mentioned above, is `undefined`) to `doSomething` 
.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `obj3.doSomething()` is inoperable is because you are assigning the `doSomething` property of the object to the *returned value* of `console.log(...)`. Since `console.log` does not return anything, it simply executes and leaves `doSomething` empty.

`obj1` and `obj2` however are essentially the same thing. If you were to replace `console.log` in `obj2` with `(x) => x * x`, then the `return` is implied and not required, however surrounding the function body in `{}` like you have in `obj1` would then still require the use of the `return` keyword.